# How do I use the transform box to re-size a photo in CS2 and constrain the proportions? I don"t want to re-size by pixels or percent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, cs2

I am placing a photo in my work space in CS2.  Then I set it to transform the shape and then try to move the corner to adjust the size it goes all crazy distorted and does not re-size proportionately.  I believe I have been able to do this in the past, but can't remember what I did to make it happen.  Just to be clear, I know how to go to re-size image and change the pixels or percentage, but I don't want to do that.  I want to re-size by moving the corner of the picture in transform mode in the work space.  Is this possible and how?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the shift key while resizing from the corners.